# How to make an iPhone spinner?

Tags: ios, radio-button, uitextfield, uipopover

I am creating an iphone application, where i am getting confuse. I need to show a control (displaying Online option) as i have mention in below screenshot. I have seen such type of controls in Android.

[image]

When user will press, it should display Offline and Online two options in one small pop up view. Selected option text will come on to the control field. How to implement or give me suggestion to show such type of field in iphone.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would suggest using a UINavigationController and a UITableViewController as destination view for displaying the two values. I think thats the way Apple does it e.g. in the settings app.

Comment: @ChrisI don't think it is the good way to do it. why UINavigationController?

Comment: Should i use ComboBox with UITableView for solution.

Comment: I suggested a NavigationController only because Apple uses it. Look at settings app -> general -> international -> calendar. This is an example where you have only 3 choices. I personally don't think that NavigationController is a good way to do this. But is there a better one?

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer here: [Any pull down or drop down menu for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400801/any-pull-down-or-drop-down-menu-for-ios)

Personally I would make a text box with an image view to make it look like a drop down box. then on tap load a `UIActionSheet` for the user to select from.