# How to use a pull down menu with storyboard

Tags: swift, drop-down-menu, uibutton, storyboard, uimenu

I'm trying to use a pull down menu in my app using the storyboard but I keep getting an error saying `"Menu does not have a valid element for default selection"`. My setup looks like this:

[image: pull down menu with menu items]

I've successfully managed to implement a pull down menu using code, following this answer: [How to show pull down button menu in IOS 14 swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877260/how-to-show-pull-down-button-menu-in-ios-14-swift) but I'd like to know how to do it using a storyboard.

I think I'm missing the assignment of the UIMenuElement to my button, because when I remove the assignment in code `button.menu = menu` it does't work either. I just can't seem to figure out how to connect the 2 using the storyboard.

Comment: I got the same error message for the same scenario, have you figured out how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure that each of your menu commands have actions associated with them; otherwise, at run time, that exception is thrown.

So, after clicking on a menu command, go to the Connections Inspector and wire up an action to your code:

[image]